# Windows is low speed in Normal Mode and good in Safe Mode

Tags: windows-xp

I have a problem with Windows XP. I when boot Windows in `Safe Mode` everything is fine but I boot windows in `Normal Mode` performance of Windows is decreased.The mouse pointer doesn't move smoothly. Is the problem related to VGA? Know anyone more?

Comment: How much memory is installed? Which Service pack level, 3 ?

Comment: 1G RAM and service pack 3

Comment: Update your graphics driver to the latest version available if you have not done it already.

Comment: Any reason you picked an one-liner answer posted 4 hours ago vs an answer that's two weeks old and that actually tells you where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load windows in safe mode and by using task manager possibility find who eat your proce4

Answer (score 4):

You may want to start the taskmanager and see what eats you cpu cycles.

When you boot in safe mode, you usually don't have you network drivers loaded and no autorun programs are started.
Could be something on your network or a background task which causes the bad performance.
See this article on how to configure autostart programs: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/270035/en-us

Answer (score 2):

Right -- sounds like something is looping and sucking up all your cycles.  Do Ctrl/Alt/Del and select "Start Task Manager", then (after waiting a few seconds for Task Manager to start up) select the "Processes" tab and click on the "CPU" column heading twice (so that a down-arrow appears in the column heading).  The guilty party will be at the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

If your mouse pointer doesn't move smoothly means , high memory load in your RAM & your CPU Usage percentage might be higher than 90 %

- Possible reasons which affects your system performance :

  -Some of the virus programs won't run in safe mode , in normal mode it will run with full CPU usage.
  -Check your drivers and software recently installed.
- Try this :
  -Go to Task manager and find the process which occupies highest memory and end the process

  -In run command type 'msconfig' and in startup tab find the start up item and its manufacturer ,uncheck if unknown manufacturer is in start up .
- Use some system tweak software available in internet .
- [Disable unnecessary Windows Services](http://www.blackviper.com/2008/05/19/black-vipers-windows-xp-x86-32-bit-service-pack-3-service-configurations/)

Answer (score 0):

I have never personally seen the cursor movement effected by a PCs performance.  It sounds like a video card driver issue as you and Moab mentioned.   In safe mode, your video driver may not be loaded relieving the issue.

More info on your resources will also help to find the answer.  Open your task manager and report back your CPU and Memory usage.